# load html file to temporary storage in sauce labs and get the file path location

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, saucelabs

I have an html file in my project workspace to validate. I have sauce lab user name and access_key to run my test on saucelabs vm.

My issue is: I want to load this html file in a temporary storage on sauce lab vm, and get the path location during run time. I have to pass this path location to my selenium driver. I went over "temporary-storage" documentation, however unable to get the path location.

I tried this:

```
public String testHTMLFile = "src/main/java/elements/fixtures/responsive.html";
SauceREST sauceREST = new SauceREST(USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY);
File resourceFile = new File(testHTMLFile);
sauceREST.uploadFile(resourceFile, resourceFile.getName());
```

Hitting GET storage, shows me that the file is there in temporary storage area.

But I need the path location. I want to supply it to Selenium - driver.get("*the temporary storage path of the html file*");

Please help. Can you give me the exact code snippet to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue. sauce-storage was the wrong approach.
Sauce-Connect was the right approach."https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Sauce+Connect+for+Testing+Behind+the+Firewall+or+on+Localhost"

In travis.yml file,add below config:

NOTE: Generate the secure encrypted username and access_key for that "particular" git hub project by following this link: "https://docs-staging.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/travis-ci/#adding-credentials-for-a-public-github-repo"

```
language:java
addons:
  sauce_connect: true
env:
global:
-secure: "encrypted sauce user name"
-secure: "encrypted sauce access key"
before_script:
- python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

In your java test set the desired capabilities:

```
`DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();`
`caps.setCapability("tunnel-identifier", System.getenv("TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER"));`
`caps.setCapability("build", System.getenv("TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"));`
`caps.setCapability("platform", "OSX 10.8");`
`caps.setCapability("version", "43.0");`
`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);`
`driver.get("http://localhost:8000/path to your file in your project workspace");`
```